# passing 3 paths as arguments from cmd to python code- first path has space

Tags: python, cmd, jmeter, arguments

I have python code that has to get 3 paths as arguments from cmd.
when i am running the command in cmd

```
python jmx_from_cmd.py """C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\" "C:\jmeter_tests\tests\" "C:\jmeter_tests\tests\Results\"
```

i put 3 """ before the first path- because there is space (Program Files)
something is not valid here, someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

split 3 paths as a string, then it will work

```
python jmx_from_cmd.py "C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\" "C:\jmeter_tests\tests\" "C:\jmeter_tests\tests\Results\"
```

Comment: i did it but got an error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: . if i print them i saw it didn't split them right. it made them one string...